# Angular 5 + angular-maps bing map

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Tride to integrate angular-maps bing to my project on Angular 5
I do everything as in the instruction ([angular-maps-github](https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps))

Imported all modules from angular-maps to my ngModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { 
    MapModule, MapAPILoader, BingMapAPILoaderConfig, 
    BingMapAPILoader, WindowRef, DocumentRef, 
    MapServiceFactory, BingMapServiceFactory 
} from "angular-maps";
...

@NgModule({
imports: [
...
MapModule.forRootBing()
...
],
providers: [
...
  {
  provide: MapAPILoader, deps: [], useFactory: MapServiceProviderFactory
  }
...
]
})
```

and added function

```
export function MapServiceProviderFactory(){
            let bc: BingMapAPILoaderConfig = new BingMapAPILoaderConfig();
            bc.apiKey ="..."; // your bing map key
            bc.branch = "experimental"; 
            return new BingMapAPILoader(bc, new WindowRef(), new DocumentRef());
}
```

Try to build my project and then i have error 
**"Cannot find namespace 'Microsoft'".**

searching a little more figure out that should add one more import

```
import { Microsoft } from "bingmaps/scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All"
```

but there is not Microsoft module in that files that is why i added

```
import { } from "bingmaps/scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All"
```

and it helps, i don't have this erorr and i have access to Microsoft.Map.

when i try to build my project there is other problem :

```
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'MyModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'MyModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation
```

now i can't understand what's the problem? Maybe someone has any ideas or maybe there are better ways to integrate bing map to angular 5 project....

Comment: Hey Anwin can you please share complete code so that it will be helpful to debug?

Comment: It's not currently compatible with Angular 5: https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps/issues/68

Comment: Yes you are right, i wrote to the creator about this issue